# Displays selection inside a readonly textbox

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub cmbPrdCde_Enter()
Dim ary As Variant, nary As Variant, r As Long
If cmbSDPFLine.Value = "Slat" Then
    cmbPrdCde.Clear
    cmbPrdCde.Value = ""
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cmbSDPFLine.Value)
        ary = .Range("B3", .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1))
        ReDim nary(1 To UBound(ary))
            For r = 1 To UBound(ary)
                nary(r) = ary(r, 1) & " (" & ary(r, 2) & ")"
            Next r
    Me.cmbPrdCde.List = nary
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

The above code places the values of Column B and C and concatenates them into one combo box on a user form. Column B contains the product code for the item and column C contains the name of the item. How do I, depending on what is selected,   display the value of just column C inside a read only text box.

Answer (score 0):

You could get your Column C text back from the comboBox.list:

```
Private Sub cmbPrdCde_Change()
x = Split(Me.cmbPrdCde.Value, " (")
Yourtextbox.Value = Left(x(1), Len(x(1)) - 1)
End Sub
```

Or you can use the listIndex and get the value from the Sheet itself

Answer (score 0):

Displaying only the value from only column C in a read-only Textbox could easily be achieved like this:

```
' set textbox to read-only
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

     ' change textbox name if required
    Me.TextBox1.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

Then in the enter event, do something like this:

```
Me.TextBox1.value = Replace(Split(Me.cmbPrdCde.Value, " (")(1), ")", vbNullstring)
```

This does presume, however, that no parentheses are used in the values of column C.

Comment: @j man Great. Please consider accepting the answer then. Thx.